# Error while Eager loading a Eloquent model with multiple relationship in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5, relationship

My `User` model have two relationships

```
public function group(){
                return $this->belongsTo('App\Group','group_id');
            }
public function profile()
            {
                return $this->hasOne('App\Profile','user_id');
            }
```

And Accessing them in Controller like

```
 $users = \App\User::with('group','profile')->get();
```

However, Retriving `Profile Model's column give error`
(Inside a @foreach loop )

```
@foreach ($users as $user)
    URL::action('ProfileController@edit',[$user->profile->id])
@foreach ($users as $user)
```

Error

```
Trying to get property of non-object 
(View: C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel1\resources\views\user\index.blade.php)
```

Debug:
while `dd($user)` gives out related data, why the error ?

P.S. `dd($user)` output link = http://bit.ly/1IxEpVk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to get id from an null profile. Please check one of your results and see that inside relations property you have profile as null

Please check first if profile is null and only after that get your field

Good luck.

Comment: Yup!! I had Injected the `$user->profile->save()` in my `UserController@store` but never updated that for admin user created before. That solved it Thanks